# How to return multiple nodes in Neo4j using Java plugin?

Tags: java, neo4j, neo4j-apoc, neo4j-plugin

I try to write a function in Java that finds nodes in my Neo4j graph database with same names and labels.

```
@UserFunction(value = "boris.example")
@Description("finds nodes with same name")

   public  ResourceIterator<Node> passName(@Name("nodeId") long nodeId)
   {
        Node nodeX = null;

        Node node = db.getNodeById( nodeId ); //Find node with spcific ID
        Object nameVal = node.getProperties("name"); //Get its name
        Label label = Label.label("VersionableObject"); //Decl. of label

        // Find nodes by label and name
        ResourceIterator<Node> nodes = db.findNodes(label, "name", nameVal); 
        nodes.close();

        return nodes;
   }
```

This  function causes following exception an refuses to start Neo4j:

"Argument `ResourceIterator<Node>` at position 0 in `passName` with
type `Label` cannot be converted to a Neo4j type: Don't know how to map `org.neo4j.graphdb.ResourceIterator` to the Neo4j Type System."

Then I tried to convert ResourceIterator to Stream using

```
Stream<Node> nodesStream = nodes.stream();
```

Same Error - Neo4j can't map Stream..

```
ResourceIterator<Node> nodes = db.findNodes(label, "name", nameVal);    

        while (nodes.hasNext()) {

            nodeX = nodes.next();

        }
        nodes.close();

return nodeX;
```

Output in Neo4j empty, even though it should find 3 nodes.

Converting the Stream to Array or List did not work as well.

Finding one node and displaying itself or its properties works, e.g.:

```
Node node = db.getNodeById( nodeId );
Map<String, Object> propertyMap = node.getProperties("name");
```

**EDIT**

After changing @UserFunction to @Procedure with mode.READ:

```
package org.neo4j.example.procedure_template;


import org.neo4j.graphdb.ResourceIterator;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Label;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Node;
import org.neo4j.logging.Log;
import org.neo4j.procedure.*;
import org.neo4j.procedure.Description;
import org.neo4j.procedure.Name;


public class FindNode {

    @Context
    public GraphDatabaseService db;

    @Context
    public Log log;


    public FindNode() {
    }

    @Procedure(value = "boris.getAllNodesWithProperty", mode = Mode.READ)
    @Description("boris.getAllNodesWithProperty - finds Node by ID and return defined Property")

       public Stream<Node> passName(@Name("nodeId") long nodeId)

       {
        Node node = db.getNodeById( nodeId );
        Object nameVal = node.getProperties("name");
        Label label = Label.label("VersionableObject");

        ResourceIterator<Node> nodes = db.findNodes(label, "name", nameVal);
        Stream<Node> nodesStream = nodes.stream();

        return nodesStream;
       }

}
```

In this case i get: "Procedures with zero output fields must be declared as VOID".

Any ideas? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Neo4j you can extend Cypher by creating some custom `user defined function` or `procedure`.

A `user defined function` is just a convertor, it's readonly, and return a single type that can be   : `long, Long, double, Double, boolean, Boolean, String, Node, Relationship, Path, Map<String, Object, or List<T>`

A `procedure` can takes arguments, perform operations on the database, and return results (as a Stream).

In your code, you have defined a `user function`, and I think what you want is a `procedure`. That's why you have the cast error from `ResourceIterator` to the `Neo4j Type System`.

You have to make those changes :

- replace `@UserFunction(value = "boris.example")` by `@Procedure(value = "boris.example", mode = Mode.READ)`
- Change the return type of your method to `Stream<Node>`

Cheers.

### Edit

A procedure must return a `pojo` or a simple type. So you have to wrap your `Node` in a pojo like this :

```
public class FindNode {

    @Context
    public GraphDatabaseService db;

    @Context
    public Log log;


    @Procedure(value = "boris.getAllNodesWithProperty", mode = Mode.READ)
    @Description("boris.getAllNodesWithProperty - finds Node by ID and return defined Property")
    public Stream<NodeResult> passName(@Name("nodeId") long nodeId)

    {
        Node node = db.getNodeById( nodeId );
        Object nameVal = node.getProperty("name");
        Label label = Label.label("VersionableObject");

        ResourceIterator<Node> nodes = db.findNodes(label, "name", nameVal);

        return nodes.stream().map( item -> new NodeResult(item));
    }

    public class NodeResult {

        public final Node node;

        public NodeResult(Node node) {
            this.node = node;
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

I tried to do so but then i get: "Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@63f85119' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the attached cause exception *"Procedures with zero output fields must be declared as VOID"*

Comment: Defined here in line 63: 
https://fossies.org/linux/neo4j/community/kernel/src/main/java/org/neo4j/kernel/impl/proc/ProcedureRegistry.java